# table schema for 2D array

Tags: mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an structure of data to store in a table that is 2d array details of this data:

> **Languages**|**Reading**|**Writing**|**listening**
>
> ---
>
> English      | Good      | Excellent | Very good
>
> French       | Excellent | Good      | Fair
>
> Persian      | Good      | Excellent | Good

I have this structure in my interface in student enrollment form when I want to add a student along the other data I should store information about their language abilities I used radio for options(good,excellent,fair,...etc) now I want to have a table to store this data separate from the main table so for any suggestion about table schema to store this data in table.

Answer (score 0):

Table structure:

> StudentLanguageId | StudentId | Language
>
> StudentLanguageReadingId | StudentLanguageId | Level
>
> StudentLanguageWritingId | StudentLanguageId | Level
>
> StudentLanguageListeningId | StudentLanguageId | Level